# Rails create a Model for a controller that uses a .group method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to collect my customers with `Spree::Order.group(:email)` (since we have a guest checkout option).

The controller is as such:

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @customers = Spree::Order.where(state: "complete").group(:email).select(
      :email, 
      'count(id) AS total_orders_count',
      'sum(payment_total) AS amount', 
      'array_agg(number) AS order_numbers', 
      'array_agg(completed_at) AS completion_dates'
      )    
  end
```

Can I create a `customer.rb` model for these @customers so I can move the logic there.  I need to `.joins(:line_items)` and filter by date, so I figure it'd be cleaner.

P.S.  As an asside...the `'sum(payment_total' AS amount` always returns `0.0` because the `payment_total` is a BigDecimal object.  What's the correct syntax for this request that would act like `'sum(payment_total.to_f)'...`.

Comment: How to cast values depends on the database used. On Postgres you would use `sum(payment_total::float) AS amount` for example.

Comment: I'm guessing you would want to create something like a `SpreeOrders` service rather than a model...

Comment: In general, queries of this complexity should be implemented in models or model concerns using scopes, not hard-coded in the controller.  Creating a Customer model is a good idea, especially if you already have a customers table.

Comment: @bill - I don't have a customers table, that's why I'm trying to figure out how this can be done.  @max - thanks, but that's still returning the 0.0, each payment total looks returns this `#<BigDecimal:7ff6529f3918,'0.499E1',18(18)> `

Comment: That is not "0.0" that is a `BigDecimal` representation of 4.99. When displaying this value you can call `to_f` and it will return 4.99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't have a `customers` table, and you're trying to abstract the concept of a guest customer out of the orders table, creating a model is a reasonable approach.

Consider the following:

```rb
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Use the `orders` table for this "virtual" model
  self.table_name = Spree::Order.table_name

  # ensure no writes ever occur from this model as a precaution
  def readonly?; true; end

  scope :with_completed_orders, ->  {
    where(state: "complete")
      .select(
        :email,
        'count(id) AS total_orders_count',
        'sum(payment_total) AS amount',
        'array_agg(number) AS order_numbers',
        'array_agg(completed_at) AS completion_dates'
      )
      .group(:email)
      .order(:email) # prevents errors - remove it and try Customer.first in the console.
  }

  scope :by_email, -> (email) { where(email: email) }

  # Default scopes are generally a no-no, but a convenience here
  def self.default_scope
    # this could be any scope that groups by :email
    self.with_completed_orders
  end

  # example of a potentially useful instance method
  def orders
    # returns a scope, which you can chain
    Spree::Order.where(email: email)
  end

end
```

The selects in the scope populate Customer instance attributes of the same name, as you probably know.

This will allow you to do things like:

```rb
customers = Customer.all
c = Customer.by_email('test@example.com')
c.amount # returns BigDecimal
c.order_numbers # returns Array 
c.orders.first # example of chaining scope for #orders instance method
```

In the controller:

```rb
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @customers = Customer.all
  end
end
```

Hopefully this gives you some ideas.

Comment: This is great!  With this direction, how would it interact with the `customers_controller.rb`?  Would it touch it at all?

Comment: Yes, that's where you would use it.  Updated the answer with an example based on your original question.